# Setup gunicorn to run with Django

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I've installed gunicorn and my django project `kb` when I cd into `kb` and run `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 kb.wsgi:application` it runs okay.

I've I run nano on `/etc/init/gunicorn.conf`

```
description "Gunicorn application server handling myproject"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]


respawn
setuid user
setgid www-data
chdir /home/ubuntu/kb

exec gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/kb/kb.sock kb.wsgi:application
```

When I run `sudo service gunicorn start`

I get `Failed to start gunicorn.service: Unit gunicorn.service not found.`

**UPDATE**

The exec line:

```
exec gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/kb/kb.sock kb.wsgi:application
```

is from an example where gunicorn is installed in a virtualenv. I've edited out the `exec virtualenv\bin\gunicorn` to `exec gunicorn`

Comment: Maybe this one helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/749135/unit-gunicorn-service-failed-to-load-no-such-file-or-directory-on-ubuntu-15-1

Comment: yes it's related the exec line I edited prior was intended for gunicorn in a virtualenv. Though this looks like it could work I would prefer figuring out if I can make it work with a gunicorn installed globally.

Comment: @SamuelMuiruri - I'm not sure I understand the relevance of virtualenv to the issue. The linked post suggests that the issue is that you should be using a `systemd` unit file such as this http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html#systemd instead of an `upstart` initialization file. What is the host OS you're trying to run this on?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using gunicorn.conf better to use the below file....

*sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service*

Add below conf setting in this file....

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=dj
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/dj/myproject
ExecStart=/home/dj/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/dj/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:app$

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Change permission to directories..

**chmod g+x /home/dj/**

**chmod g+r /home/dj/**

**sudo chgrp www-data /home/dj/**

Note : please make sure that the gunicorn should be within the virtualenv..

**FYI: pip install gunicorn** Under virtualenv

Hope this helps you..
It's working for me..